# What's the difference between navigation.navigate() and <Link /> in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm also using react-native-web in my project. The navigation.navigate seems to be working fine on web. Why would I need to or in what cases I should use  ?

Answer (score 1):

navigation.navigate() and  are both used for navigation in a React application, but they are used in different contexts and with different libraries.

navigation.navigate() in React Navigation (React Native):
In a React Native application using React Navigation, the navigation.navigate() function is used to programmatically navigate between different screens within your app.

Example:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
const MyComponent = () => {
const navigation = useNavigation();

const goToDetailsScreen = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Details');
};

return (
    <Button title="Go to Details" onPress={goToDetailsScreen} />
  );
};
```

.

in React Router (React for Web):
In a web application using React Router, the  component is used to create links that allow users to navigate between different routes within your web app. It generates an anchor () tag that, when clicked, triggers a navigation to the specified route without a full page reload.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
return (
   <Link to="/details">Go to Details</Link>
  );
};
```